# React Apollo. Diffrences between writeQuery and writeFragment?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I'm new at Apollo React and i a bit stuck... I can't figure out about differences between writeQuery and writeFragment / readFragment and readQuery
Can somebody help me with that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out the docs under the [API - CACHE -> InMemoryCache section](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/cache/InMemoryCache/#writequery).